# rosserial on ROS Kinetic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
Can i install rosserial on ROS kinetic? if yes, can you tell me how please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236351/rosserial-on-ros-kinetic/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit (2019-11-12): `rosserial` has long since been released for Kinetic (and Melodic). If possible try to use `apt` to install it (but make sure to be using a supported OS+platform combination (ie: `amd64`,  `arm64` or `armhf` with Debian or Ubuntu), check the [status pages](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/)):

```
sudo apt install ros-$ROS_DISTRO-rosserial
```

(replace `$ROS_DISTRO` with your version of ROS, ie: `kinetic` or `melodic`)

---

Original answer: it will be eventually on the repositories so you can install it using apt-get install
according to:  https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/issues/223

In any case you can download the code to any of your catkin workspaces and build it:

```
 mkdir -p rosserial_ws/src 
 cd rosserial_ws/src  
 git pull https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial
 cd .. 
 catkin_make
```

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2016-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1